# How to change RibbonType without Visual Designer for an Outlook add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbonx

I am using an open source Outlook add-in [[Link]](https://github.com/certsocietegenerale/NotifySecurity), however, the add-in only appears on the Explorer ribbon (the main Outlook window), however, when I open an email it does not appear, I want to change this behavior so it appears in both Message/Read window and the Explorer window, I have read about RibbonType but what I believe that needs Visual Designer and this project does not use it, how can this be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [add-in project](https://github.com/certsocietegenerale/NotifySecurity) uses ribbon XML for customizing the Outlook UI. It seems you need to edit the [Ribbon1.xml](https://github.com/certsocietegenerale/NotifySecurity/blob/master/Ribbon1.xml) and [Ribbon1.cs](https://github.com/certsocietegenerale/NotifySecurity/blob/master/Ribbon1.cs) files to include the required customizations. Read more about the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thanks! I will read and update :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue (thanks to @Eugene) by simply adding the following lines in Ribbon1.xml

Original Ribbon1.xml

```
  <tabs>
  <tab idMso="TabMail" visible="true">
      <group  id="grousp1"  getLabel="GetGroupLabel" visible="true">
        <button id="button1D"
         size="large" 
         getLabel="GetButtonLabel"
         getSupertip="GetSupertipLabel"
         getImage="GetImage"
         onAction="ShowMessageClick"></button>
      </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
```

Ribbon1.xml after modification

```
    <tabs>

    <tab idMso="TabReadMessage" visible="true">
        <group  id="grousp2"  getLabel="GetGroupLabel" visible="true">
            <button id="button2D"
            size="large"
            getLabel="GetButtonLabel"
            getSupertip="GetSupertipLabel"
            getImage="GetImage"
            onAction="ShowMessageClick"></button>
        </group>
    </tab>
  <tab idMso="TabMail" visible="true">
      <group  id="grousp1"  getLabel="GetGroupLabel" visible="true">
        <button id="button1D"
         size="large" 
         getLabel="GetButtonLabel"
         getSupertip="GetSupertipLabel"
         getImage="GetImage"
         onAction="ShowMessageClick"></button>
      </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
```